# Bootstrap, align text to the right with strong tag within it

Tags: html, django, twitter-bootstrap

This might be a silly question, but how can I align piece of my text inside Alert tag in Bootstrap to the right, while keeping a piece within this text in `<strong>` tag?

For now I have this piece of code:

```
    <div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">
        Error number: <strong>{{ error.error_number }}</strong>
        Active since: <strong> {{ error.datetime }}</strong></br>
        Message: <strong>{{ error.error_message }}</strong>
    </div>
```

Which results in

[image: first screenshot]

So far so good, but the "active since and datetime" I want to be aligned to the right. So I tried using `p class="text-right` tag, but this will override `strong` tag, moreover it will put whatever is inside to new line. So this code:

```
    <div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">
        Error number: <strong>{{ error.error_number }}</strong>
        <p class="text-right">Active since: <strong> {{ error.datetime }}</strong></p></br>
        Message: <strong>{{ error.error_message }}</strong>
    </div>
```

will look like

[image: this]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a little bit of help from [mohamedHabib](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2100874/mohamedhabib) I tweaked my code, so I used `span` instead of `p`, moreover I used `class="pull-right"` instead of `class="text-right"`. So the code looks like this:

```
    <div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">
        Error number: <strong>{{ error.error_number }}</strong>
        <span class="pull-right">Active since: <strong> {{ error.datetime }}</strong></span></br>
        Message: <strong>{{ error.error_message }}</strong>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a span instead of p :

```
<div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">

    Error number: <strong>{{ error.error_number }}</strong>
    <span class="text-right">Active since: <strong> {{ error.datetime }}</strong></span>
    <br/>
    Message: <strong>{{ error.error_message }}</strong>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jjL3zu4u/

Comment: While this keeps the `strong` tag, it results the same way as 1st example.